# Get rows based on nested minimums of multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to query to get rows based on (nested) minimums of multiple fields?

Have a table with rows of the form:

```
[a, b, c, id, date, line, code, d, e]
```

the relation between id, date, line, and code is:

```
one(id)->many(date)->many(line)->one(code)
```

Would like to get the `id`s mapped to the `code` corresponding to the minimum line of the minimum date, so given a table like:

```
[a1, b1, id1, date11,            line111,             code1]
[a2, b2, id1, date12 (= date11), line122 (< line111), code2]
[a3, b3, id2, date21,            line211,             code3]
[a4, b4, id2, date22 (< date21), line221 (> line211), code4]

Where 
idX => "Xth id", 
dateXY => "Yth date of Xth id", 
and lineXYZ => "Z line of the Yth date of the Xth id".
```

would end up with a table like:

```
[a2, b2, id1, date11, line122, code2]
[a4, b4, id2, date22, line221, code4]
```

Hope this is not a duplicate (could not find solution from preliminary googling for *nested* minimums).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down into the smaller problems at hand here.

1. Apply `row_number()` to both the `[line]` and `[date]` columns, ordered so that row #1 is the "minimum" as you describe.
2. Then simply `select` from the table where both row #'s are 1.

Something like (this was written in notepad, may not compile and might not be ordered by your needs):

```
;with c as (
    select
        id
        ,line
        ,row_number() over (partition by id order by date asc, line asc) as rn
    from
        dbo.yourTable
)

select
    id
    ,line
from
    c
where
    rn = 1
```

Comment: I think you just want one RN, `...ORDER BY Date ASC, Line ASC`